# Inconsistent click handling when using :active pseudo class

Tags: html, css

Can anyone explain why the click handler is not invoked consistently in this example?

http://jsfiddle.net/4QBnf/

For instance, if you click in the upper left half of the div, it does not reliably increment the counter.

If I remove the padding-top from this block it works just fine:

```
.click-check:active {
   background-color:blue;
   padding-top: 25px;
}
```

I have tested this in a number of different browsers and it behaves the same way.

Answer (score 3):

I found two possible issues with your code. You can view the fixes here:

http://jsfiddle.net/4QBnf/6/

### CSS Box Model vs jQuery Box Model

Whenever you click on the top half of your box, you aren't technically clicking on `.click-check`, you are actually clicking on `.count`. This image shows the location of `.count` relative to `.click-check`:

[image: The highlighted area is the area of <code>.count</code>]

jQuery counts this as a click on `.click-check`, but CSS doesn't. The number increments, but the CSS "active" effect isn't applied.

You can resolve this by removing the `.count` div and placing everything inside of `.click-check`.

### jQuery Counter

The second issue is with your jQuery code. The code currrently reads:

```
$('.click-check').click(function() { $('.count').html(count++); });
```

`count` isn't increased until after this line is done. This means that the first click appears to have no effect.

This line will increment `count`, then display it to the user:

```
$('.click-check').click(function() { $('.click-check').html(++count); });
```

I've applied both updates to your example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/4QBnf/6/

### Update

An alternate way to resolve the issue is to do everything through jQuery. This synchronizes all of the appearance and logic into a single box-model interpretation.

```
var count=0;
$('.click-check').mousedown(function() { 
    $('.click-check').addClass("active");
    $('.click-check').html(++count);

    setTimeout(function(){ 
       $('.click-check').removeClass("active");
    }, 50);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4QBnf/15/

Comment: Thank you for that, it is very helpful! You will notice, though, that even with your suggested changes, there is a place just below the text where you can click and the number will not increment.

Comment: @LindenMelvin: How strange! It looks like it works fine in IE and Firefox, but it doesn't work in Chrome.  It looks like there's a workaround: if you use the `mouseup` or `mousedown` functions instead of `click`, then it works better. http://jsfiddle.net/4QBnf/10/  http://jsfiddle.net/4QBnf/11/

Comment: Thanks guys for this question/answer. Weird issue. Probably caused by nature of click event, since *onClick will only trigger when the left mouse button is pressed and released on the same object*

Comment: btw, [here's](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/123-if-it-moves-when-you-click-make-something-stick/) good article explaining similar issue.